# If random variables $X$ and $Y$ have the same moment for all order, then they have the same distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

I want to know If random variables $X$ and $Y$ have the same moment for all order, then they have the same.

I know this statement is true if the space of $X$ and $Y$ are compact by Weierstrass approximation.

But does it still hold true if they can take any real value?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem

Comment: So, no. See  [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84219/whether-distributions-with-the-same-moments-are-identical)  and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25010/identity-of-moment-generating-functions) for counter examples with unbounded $x>0$ .